# Python: I want to build a list that centers by size of keys, TypeError

Tags: python

Iterate over size of keys / values in a dictionary --> adjust by list size based on the highest length.

I get that the problem is the wrong type of return value. I just don't know how to fix it.

```
def printPicnic(itemsDict):
    leftWidth = 10
    rightWidth = 10
    for key, value in itemsDict.items():
        if len(key) > leftWidth:
            leftWidth = len(key)
        if  len(value) > rightWidth:
            rightWidth = len(value)
    print('PICNIC ITEMS'.center(leftWidth + rightWidth, '-'))
    for k, v in itemsDict.items():
        print(k.ljust(leftWidth, '.') + str(v).rjust(rightWidth))

picnicItems = {'sandwichesssssssssssssssssss': 4, 'apples': 12, 'cups': 4, 'cookies': 8000}
printPicnic(picnicItems)

    if  len(value) > rightWidth:
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Comment: Add `print(repr(value))` before that line to find out what `value` is at that point. For the future, learn to use a debugger to step through code and inspect variables.

Answer (score 0):

You want the integer that is the value in the dictionary as string. Than you can use `len(value)` and do the according calculations to get is displayed properly.

Add `value = str(value)`:

```
def printPicnic(itemsDict):
    leftWidth = 10
    rightWidth = 10
    for key, value in itemsDict.items():
        value = str(value)
        if len(key) > leftWidth:
            leftWidth = len(key)
        if  len(value) > rightWidth:
            rightWidth = len(value)
    print('PICNIC ITEMS'.center(leftWidth + rightWidth, '-'))
    for k, v in itemsDict.items():
        print(k.ljust(leftWidth, '.') + str(v).rjust(rightWidth))

picnicItems = {'sandwichesssssssssssssssssss': 4, 'apples': 12, 'cups': 4, 'cookies': 8000}
printPicnic(picnicItems)
```

prints:

```
-------------PICNIC ITEMS-------------
sandwichesssssssssssssssssss         4
apples......................        12
cookies.....................      8000
cups........................         4
```